# DP top left vs bottom right table filling. Which to use when?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are many problems which require table filling from top left(ex: Edit Distance) and starting from bottom right(ex: Palindromic substrings).
Is there any intuitive explanation of which to use when?
Reference:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/
https://leetcode.com/problems/palindromic-substrings/discuss/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direction of the table itself doesn't make any difference, it's isomorphic under a trivial indexing transformation. That is, you can trivially flip the table around in any dimension by subtracting that index from the size of that dimension. That doesn't make any difference and you could say that the algorithm doesn't even "know" that you're doing that, you could even make a table-like object that abstracts that transformation away so the code looks exactly the same but deep down there is a table being filled in the opposite direction.

The order in which the sub-problems are solved matters, it must obey the dependency structure. Finding an appropriate order to solve the sub-problems in is actually an important step in the "turn recursion into DP"-checklist, it is often overlooked because usually there is some trivial order that works that you don't even have to think about. But for example, here is the structure of the Fibonacci recursion, courtesy of wikipedia:

[image: Fibonacci graph]

What you can see here (and what you also immediately obvious from the recursive definition) is that invocations with a some argument only depend on invocations with smaller arguments. Therefore, filling the table in order from lowest argument to higher is a valid order, which guarantees that when a cell in the table is needed, it has already been computed. (usually this is optimized further to keep only the previous two items rather than all preceding, but that is not the point here)

It is not always that simple, especially in higher dimensions, but in your example of Edit Distance: (src: geeksforgeeks.org)

[image: Edit Distance structure]

You can see that every eD(x,y) depends only on eD(x-dx,y-dy) where dx and dy are 0 or 1 and not *both* 0, which is satisfied by *many* orders, such as (not limited to):

- lexicographical on (y,x) (presented in their answer)
- lexicographical on (x,y) (just invert the inner and outer loop)
- anti-diagonals
- starting at 0,0, extending the rectangle of filled cells by 1 step down, then right, down again, etc
- extending it by k steps
- shrinking the rectangle of empty cells by a step down, then right, etc
- quarter-circles of expanding radius with the center at 0,0

All you have to preserve is that when eD(a,b) is calculated, everything it needs has already been calculated. This leaves a lot of freedom, you could even take all of the empty cells that have filled cells to their left and top and pick one to fill at random. However, an order that definitely does *not* work for this problem is filling the table starting at (m,n) - just think about which cells it would need: cells that you haven't filled yet (also if you could do it, then you could compute the final answer in one step).

In terms of the dependency graph, any topological order will work.